# How to find distinct set of tags from multiple entities in app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am writing a system on app engine that collects "samples" and provides services for querying and analyzing the samples.  The data model for a sample looks similar to this:

```
class Sample(ndb.Model):
   category  = ndb.StringProperty()
   name      = ndb.StringProperty()
   data      = ndb.JsonProperty()
   timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
   tags      = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)
```

As you can see, for each sample there is a set of string tags.  For example something like:

```
['CustomerA', '2.0.5', 'featureX', 'logTypeB', ...]
```

I have a handler that allows querying over all samples in the system based upon filters on the base properties and including a set of tags to require.  Note: the results set can be very large, so the query supports paging/limits so I return data a bit at a time.  That all works.

Now when I am putting a user interface on top of this I would like a way to present the user with an autocomplete field for entering additional tags to further filter the results.  So for example if they have restricted it down to samples with the following tags:

```
Sample(..., tags=['CustomerA', '2.0.5', 'featureX'])
Sample(..., tags=['CustomerA', '2.0.5', 'featureY'])
Sample(..., tags=['CustomerB', '2.0.5', 'featureX'])
Sample(..., tags=['CustomerB', '2.0.5', 'featureX'])
Sample(..., tags=['CustomerB', '2.0.5', 'featureY'])
```

then I want to show them an autocomple that includes:

```
['CustomerA', 'CustomerB', '2.0.5', 'featureX', 'featureY']
```

In other words I need a handler that can return a unique list of tags that exist in the current set of results.  The problem is that I can't see anyway to do this in App Engine without iterating over all result samples (potentially very large) and building up a set of unique tags to return.

I could keep a separate set of entities for all tags in the system, but this doesn't solve the problem either. It would allow me to quickly find all the tags that exist over all the Samples in the system, but not restrict it to the set of Samples that pass the current filter.

Any ideas on what I could do to implement this in a reasonable way?

Comment: I never found a good way to do this.  For now I am just using a list of all the known tags across all Samples.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, is by saving the tags in a separate entity which is used solely for the autocomplete. Since the tag names are unique, you can use the tag as the entity key. This can be made simple using the ndb model hooks. For example:

```
class SampleTag(ndb.Model):
  tag = ndb.StringProperty()

class Sample(ndb.Model):
  category  = ndb.StringProperty()
  name      = ndb.StringProperty()
  data      = ndb.JsonProperty()
  timestamp = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
  tags      = ndb.StringProperty(repeated = True)

  def _pre_put_hook(self):
    for tag in self.tags:
      SampleTag.get_or_insert(name=tag)
```

Then you can use the values in SampleTag to display in your autocomplete.

This is just an example - it's not very efficient, especially if you have long lists of tags. To improve it, you should determine which tags (if any) have been added since last save, and only loop through those. Also, you may wish to use async calls, or maybe delegate the _pre_put routine entirely to a taskqueue, which will speed up the time it takes to put() your models.

Also, this doesn't handle deletion. This is a bit more tricky, as you cannot know in advance if the tag exists elsewhere. To do this, I'd use a cron job to periodically check if your tags exist.

Comment: I am working on a similar method to this for now.  I still don't quite like it though because the autocomplete may show tags that don't actually exist in the current result set.  It would be kind of like using google search's autocomplete and no matter what you type it keeps showing every word in their entire web index.  Not too user friendly. :(